# Every cubic inch of air seems 'accounted' for: verb or adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 1440) has this subsection

> **Adjectival passives with the negative prefix *un*** 
> We have noted that such examples as the following are unambiguously adjectival because there are no corresponding verbs *unrepair*, *unaccount*, *unsee*: 
> [43]    i           *The vehicle had to go **unrepaired** for several months.* 
>            ii         *Nearly half the money was **unaccounted for**.* 
>            iii        *He had remained **unseen** throughout the meeting.*
> [...] Secondly, the adjective may incorporate a preposition, as in [ii]. Although we have argued that in *We accounted for more than half the money* the sequence *accounted for* is not a verb, and not a syntactic constituent, the *unaccounted for* of [ii] is a **compound adjective**. The difference in status is reflected in the fact that the verb can be separated from the preposition whereas in the adjectival construction the parts are inseparable. Compare *We have **accounted** already **for** the money* and **The money was **unaccounted** still **for***.
> Thirdly, the morphological process of forming such negative adjectives is highly productive, and in many cases the form without the prefix occurs in verbal but not adjectival passives. For example, *unseen* is an adjective, but *seen* is not: compare [43iii] with **He had remained seen throughout the meeting.*

With this in mind, let's take a look at the following passage from [a 2013 New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/11/24/arts/dance/at-the-ballet-nosebleed-seats-have-perks.html):

> One reason many 19th-century ballets are called classics is in their mastery of patterns. The geometries we see in “Giselle,” “La Bayadère,” “Swan Lake” and “The Sleeping Beauty” remain the archetypes for opera-house-scale legibility. But here, Balanchine, drawing from their precedent, remains the master. 
> More than anyone else, he knew how to make movement animate all of the box of space behind the proscenium arch. Every cubic inch of air seems *accounted for* — most powerfully if you saw his ballets danced by his own company in his lifetime.

According to CGEL's analysis, the *accounted for* of the last sentence seems to be a compound adjective. And in CGEL's [43 ii], the *unaccounted* is an adjective.

The question is whether the *accounted* in the NYT article is a verb or an adjective. If it's a verb, the verb phrase *accounted for* somehow functions as a compound adjective. If it's an adjective, *accounted for* is not a verb phrase but an adjective phrase. Which is it?

### EDIT

I have what I think is an important question about CGEL's claim:

> [T]he verb can be separated from the preposition whereas in the adjectival construction the parts are inseparable.

To support the claim, CGEL shows this example:

> (1)      *We have **accounted** already **for** the money.*

Here, the verb ***accounted*** can be separated from the preposition **for**.

Now, the passive construction of (1) is:

> (1')      *The money has been **accounted** already **for** by us.*

Here, ***accounted*** is still a verb, but can it be also separated from the preposition ***for***? Does (1') work? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148386/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-every-cubic-inch-of-air-seems-accounted-for-ver); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I find it unacceptable too.  And 'We have accounted already for the money' grates. 'We have already accounted for the money' or 'We have accounted for the money already' (or in rare contexts a fronted adverb, or after 'we'), please.

Comment: The EDIT seems to transform this into a different question; are you asking specifically if it's separable, rather than asking for the part of speech of accounted? Whether it's separable might be provable without any grammatical knowledge merely by finding examples (I can't find anything in COCA but may not be using the best search terms).

Comment: @StuartF No, the question remains the same. The EDIT is simply questioning BillJ's comment.